# change shirt color with gd library

Tags: php, gd

i m trying to change color of a shirt. here is my code in its simplest form.

```
$imgname = "me.jpg";
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg ($imgname);
imagetruecolortopalette($im,false, 255);

$index = imagecolorclosest ( $im, 96, 132, 194 ); // get COlor
imagecolorset($im,$index,92,92,92); // SET NEW COLOR

$imgname = "result.jpg";
imagejpeg($im, $imgname ); // save image as gif
//imagedestroy($im);
```

but this code does change only specific color. You can see in attached image.
[image]

i want whole shirt color changed from blue to grey. is it possible with GD library or any other library? If yes how??

Comment: You'll probably need ImageMagick for this. And it's not going to be easy even there. Please add some more background - why does this need to be automatic?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a library to do this automatically because there's so much blue in the background unless you use a mask to apply the change only to the shirt.

Comment: The title of your question is just awesome

Comment: @pekka in fact i want to allow users to design shirts online. I have different kind of shirts. i want my users to choose a color of shirt. i will be using png with transparent background.

Comment: @mysterious but the image you show above isn not a PNG with a transparent background, is it?

Comment: @juhana i will be using png image. this was just for practice to see if it is possible or not? So if i use a png , i can do this?

Comment: @pekka no its jpeg but i can switch to transparent png images. If i use transparent png images then shirt color is changeable?

Comment: If you use transparent png you can even just overlap the images, no need to process them.

Comment: @pirsy u mean swap images..right? i don not want to swap image as shirt color depends on user input. they can choose any color for which i don't have any image.

Answer (score 1):

Using GD to accomplish this seems like using chainsaw to slice bread. An easier (and I think better) way to handle this would be to have the shirt be a transparent PNG with transparent shadows in the correct places. Then you can simply change the background color of the image container using any number of freely available color pickers. Since the shirt is transparent, it then becomes the color of the background (blue, gray, whatever). Once the user has selected a color that works, you can pass that hex color to the back-end along with the rest of the order information (size, etc).